# Pinecone filter regex hack

Tags: pinecone

I have the following problem. I have a metadata field that's essentially a file path (e.g., /root/a/b/c/d.txt).

I want to create a filter that matches a specific ancestor directory. But since Pinecone currently doesn't support regex, I'm resorting to the following hack:

Create N metadata fields, 1 for each directory level, then do a fan out for the path, then use an $eq filter at query time. So if a vector has the path of "/a/b/c/d.txt" I would have:

```
'path_1': '/a'
'path_2': '/a/b'
'path_3': '/a/b/c'
'path_4': '/a/b/c/d.txt'
```

Only issue is there is a limit to how large N can be, but I can't think of a better solution. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm struggline with a similar problem. Pinecone has promised regex support at some point, but until then this might be the best hack. You might be able to use a `$nin - (Not in array)` filter instead, but you still have the issue of a large N. 

Alternatively you could store extra metadata fields and filter off of those. i.e. if you want to search by a top level directory, create a new field for that.